# Invalid Data Type error while casting PL/SQL Array to Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL stored proc which needs to return a RefCursor type object as output parameter.

```
PROCEDURE usp_appnt_stts_driver_wraper2
( in_req_src_system_id   IN NUMBER,
  in_req_user_info       IN VARCHAR2,
  out_response_rec1      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

At the end of the SP, I am able to return **Hard Coded** values to my front end by using a Select Statement.

```
OPEN out_response_rec1 FOR 
SELECT 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data 4' FROM DUAL;
```

This works fine. But I need to send the data which I am getting from an Array.

The Array is populated like this,

```
FOR g_index IN g_slsnetoutbndarr.FIRST..g_slsnetoutbndarr.LAST

LOOP

  out_response_rec.EXTEND;
  IF g_SlsnetOutbndArr(g_index).Rectypdesc IS NOT NULL THEN   
    out_response_rec(g_index).Rectypdesc   := g_SlsnetOutbndArr(g_index).Rectypdesc ;
    out_response_rec(g_index).Recdetltcode := g_SlsnetOutbndArr(g_index).Recdetltcode;
    out_response_rec(g_index).RecDetlDesc  := g_SlsnetOutbndArr(g_index).RecDetlDesc ;
  END IF;

 END LOOP;
```

So at the end of this code, the Array Object `out_response_rec` has all the values I need.

But How do I transfer these values in the RefCursor output parameter?

**Update 1**

I have tried to create a new data type in the Package specification.

```
TYPE  SlsnetOutbndRec IS RECORD(
Rectypdesc    VARCHAR2(30),
Recdetltcode  NUMBER,
RecDetlDesc  VARCHAR2(130));

TYPE SlsnetOutbndTabArr IS TABLE OF SlsnetOutbndRec;
```

Finally I have tried to Cast the Array to table in my SP as

```
OPEN out_response_rec_result FOR
SELECT * FROM TABLE (Cast(out_response_rec AS SlsnetOutbndTabArr));
```

But this is throwing an `Invalid Data Type` error. The SP does not recognize the new data types I created.

Comment: So what populates your driving array, `g_slsnetoutbndarr`?

Comment: Hi, it comes from a 3rd party SP from another package so we can not see what is inside it.

Comment: There are multiple data types that could be considered an "Array" - Is `g_slsnetoutbndarr` a collection, `VARRAY` or an associative array? Also, does it contain an object type or a record?

Comment: What happens if you try it without the `CAST()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So at the end of this code, the Array Object out_response_rec has all
>   the values I need.
>
> But How do I transfer these values in the RefCursor output parameter?

As I could understand, you wanted to use a `SYS_REFCUSOR` to get the output of a `Query` plus the values that are in `collection` which is being populated by another `Procedure`.  I have come up with a solution for your requirement see below inline explaination:

```
--Create a Object in Place of Record since we cannot use a PLSQL scope compnenet in SQL scope in Oracle 11g and below
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SlsnetOutbndRec IS OBJECT
   (
      Rectypdesc     VARCHAR2 (30),
      Recdetltcode   NUMBER,
      RecDetlDesc    VARCHAR2 (130)
   );

--Create a table type of the Object   
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE SlsnetOutbndTabArr IS TABLE OF SlsnetOutbndRec;
/

--Procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE combined_rslt (var OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   v_var   SlsnetOutbndTabArr := SlsnetOutbndTabArr ();

   l_var   SlsnetOutbndTabArr := SlsnetOutbndTabArr ();
BEGIN
   --Populating the collection
   v_var.EXTEND;
   v_var (1) := SlsnetOutbndRec ('ABC', 1, 'A');

   OPEN VAR FOR
      SELECT 'CDE', 2, 'B' FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL -- Combining the result of collection with the result of query
      SELECT *
        FROM TABLE (v_var) t;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Execution :

```
DECLARE
   x   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   a   VARCHAR2 (30);
   b   NUMBER;
   c   VARCHAR2 (130);
BEGIN
   combined_rslt (var => x);

   LOOP
      FETCH x INTO a, b, c;

      EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (a || ' ' || b || '  ' || c);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Results:

```
SQL> /  
CDE 2  B
ABC 1  A

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the types in the SQL scope (not the PL/SQL scope) if you want to use them in SQL statements (in versions prior to Oracle 12):

```
CREATE TYPE  SlsnetOutbndRec IS OBJECT(
  Rectypdesc    VARCHAR2(30),
  Recdetltcode  NUMBER,
  RecDetlDesc  VARCHAR2(130)
)
/

CREATE TYPE SlsnetOutbndTabArr IS TABLE OF SlsnetOutbndRec
/
```

Then you can use it in your procedure (assuming your 3rd party data type is a collection or a `VARRAY`):

```
PROCEDURE usp_appnt_stts_driver_wraper2(
  in_req_src_system_id    IN  NUMBER,
  in_req_user_info        IN  VARCHAR2,
  out_response_rec_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  out_response_rec SlsnetOutbndTabArr := SlsnetOutbndTabArr();
  g_slsnetoutbndarr ThirdPartyDataType := Get_From_3rd_party_Package();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. g_slsnetoutbndarr.COUNT LOOP
    IF g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Rectypdesc IS NOT NULL THEN
      out_response_rec.EXTEND;
      out_response_rec := SlsnetOutbndRec(
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Rectypdesc,
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Recdetltcode,
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).RecDetlDesc
      );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN out_response_rec_result FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE( out_response_rec );
END;
```

If the 3rd party data type is an associative array then:

```
  ...
IS
  out_response_rec SlsnetOutbndTabArr   := SlsnetOutbndTabArr();
  g_slsnetoutbndarr ThirdPartyDataType  := Get_From_3rd_party_Package();
  i                 ThirdPartyIndexType := g_slsnetoutbndarr.FIRST;
BEGIN
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Rectypdesc IS NOT NULL THEN
      out_response_rec.EXTEND;
      out_response_rec := SlsnetOutbndRec(
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Rectypdesc,
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).Recdetltcode,
        g_SlsnetOutbndArr(i).RecDetlDesc
      );
    END IF;
    i := g_slsnetoutbndarr.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

...
```